# Snakemake cluster config in combination with DRMMA

Tags: cluster-computing, snakemake, drmaa

I have a question related to drmma and the cluster config file in snakemake.

Currently i have a pipeline and I submit jobs to the cluster using drmma with the following command:

```
snakemake --drmaa " -q short.q -pe smp 8 -l membycore=4G" --jobs 100 -p file1/out file2/out file3/out
```

The problem is that some of the rules/jobs require less or more resources. I though that if i used the json cluster file I would be able to submit the jobs with different resources. My json file looks like this:

```
{
    "__default__":
    {
        "-q":"short.q",
        "-pe":"smp 1",
        "-l":"membycore=4G"
    },
    "job1":
    {
        "-q":"short.q",
        "-pe":"smp 8",
        "-l":"membycore=4G"
    },
    "job2":
    {
        "-q":"short.q",
        "-pe":"smp 8",
        "-l":"membycore=4G"
    }
}
```

When I run the following command my jobs (job1 and job2) are submitted with default options and not with the custom ones:

```
snakemake --jobs 100 --cluster-config cluster.json --drmaa -p file1/out file2/out file3/out
```

What am I doing wrong? Is it that I cannot combine the drmaa option with the cluster-config file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the cluster config file simply allows you do define variables that are later used in `--cluster/--cluster-sync/--drmaa` depending on the defined placeholders. There's no DRMAA specific magic involved here. Have a look at [the corresponding section in the documentation](https://bitbucket.org/snakemake/snakemake/wiki/Documentation#markdown-header-cluster-configuration) again.

Maybe an example makes things clearer:

Cluster config:

```
{
    "__default__":
    {
      "time" : "02:00:00",
      "mem" : 1G,
    },
    # more rule specific definitions here...
}
```

Example snakemake arguments to make use of the above:

```
 --drmaa " -pe OpenMP {threads} -l mem_free={cluster.mem} -l h_rt={cluster.time}"
```

or

```
--cluster-sync "qsub -sync y -pe OpenMP {threads} -l mem_free={cluster.mem} -l h_rt={cluster.time}"
```

`cluster.time` and `cluster.mem` will be replaced accordingly per rule.

Andreas

Comment: See also Simon's answer in your crossposting: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/snakemake/D4enw1jt7iQ